# Eclipse Won't Compile/Run Code Pasted Into the Source Folder, Only Ant Build Available

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, build, compilation

I've tried looking at many other pages and nothing has seemed to solve the problem. I have a program that was written on another computer, and I would like to work on it on the computer I am currently using. I have a bunch of .java files from the other computer and I've put them into the source folder of a Java project I've just created on the computer I'm using, as I'm trying to reproduce the project on the computer I'm currently using. However when I try to run the code it only lets me use ant build. How can I get it to run normally? I do have a main method and I'm trying to run it from that main method.

Comment: What do you mean by "it only lets me use ant build"? What button or menu are you clicking?

Comment: When hitting Run (the green triangle at the top)

Answer (score 0):

Yo you may have to make a new project then copy and paste the code in to the package explorer.
Here's a video I found that may help you out. Hit me back if this helps.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOGxozUTm3Q